# Getting rid of the warning "The following columns ... have been ignored" and "ValueError: batch_size should be a positive integer value ..."

Tags: transformer, python-3.x, huggingface

I train a fine-tuning model with the PyTorch Trainer class:

```py
bln_truncation = False

dataset = load_dataset("text", data_files={"train": file_path})

block_size = 512
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", truncation=bln_truncation)

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./" + model_name,
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=num_train_epochs,
    per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
    save_steps=save_steps,
)
#     print(next(model.parameters()).device)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
)
#     print(next(model.parameters()).device)

trainer.train()
```

I get the warning and error:

```shell
PyTorch: setting up devices
The default value for the training argument `--report_to` will change in v5 (from all installed integrations to none). In v5, you will need to use `--report_to all` to get the same behavior as now. You should start updating your code and make this info disappear :-).
The following columns in the training set don't have a corresponding argument in `DataParallel.forward` and have been ignored: attention_mask, input_ids, text. If attention_mask, input_ids, text are not expected by `DataParallel.forward`,  you can safely ignore this message.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [18], line 36
     28 trainer = Trainer(
     29     model=model,
     30     args=training_args,
     31     data_collator=data_collator,
     32     train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
     33 )
     35 # Start training
---> 36 trainer.train()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1317, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1312     self.model_wrapped = self.model
   1314 inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(
   1315     self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1316 )
-> 1317 return inner_training_loop(
   1318     args=args,
   1319     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1320     trial=trial,
   1321     ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1322 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1329, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1327 self._train_batch_size = batch_size
   1328 # Data loader and number of training steps
-> 1329 train_dataloader = self.get_train_dataloader()
   1331 # Setting up training control variables:
   1332 # number of training epochs: num_train_epochs
   1333 # number of training steps per epoch: num_update_steps_per_epoch
   1334 # total number of training steps to execute: max_steps
   1335 total_train_batch_size = args.train_batch_size * args.gradient_accumulation_steps * args.world_size

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:769, in Trainer.get_train_dataloader(self)
    759     return DataLoader(
    760         train_dataset,
    761         batch_size=self.args.per_device_train_batch_size,
   (...)
    764         pin_memory=self.args.dataloader_pin_memory,
    765     )
    767 train_sampler = self._get_train_sampler()
--> 769 return DataLoader(
    770     train_dataset,
    771     batch_size=self._train_batch_size,
    772     sampler=train_sampler,
    773     collate_fn=data_collator,
    774     drop_last=self.args.dataloader_drop_last,
    775     num_workers=self.args.dataloader_num_workers,
    776     pin_memory=self.args.dataloader_pin_memory,
    777     worker_init_fn=seed_worker,
    778 )

File /srv/home/seid/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:357, in DataLoader.__init__(self, dataset, batch_size, shuffle, sampler, batch_sampler, num_workers, collate_fn, pin_memory, drop_last, timeout, worker_init_fn, multiprocessing_context, generator, prefetch_factor, persistent_workers, pin_memory_device)
    353             sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    355 if batch_size is not None and batch_sampler is None:
    356     # auto_collation without custom batch_sampler
--> 357     batch_sampler = BatchSampler(sampler, batch_size, drop_last)
    359 self.batch_size = batch_size
    360 self.drop_last = drop_last

File /srv/home/seid/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py:232, in BatchSampler.__init__(self, sampler, batch_size, drop_last)
    226 def __init__(self, sampler: Union[Sampler[int], Iterable[int]], batch_size: int, drop_last: bool) -> None:
    227     # Since collections.abc.Iterable does not check for `__getitem__`, which
    228     # is one way for an object to be an iterable, we don't do an `isinstance`
    229     # check here.
    230     if not isinstance(batch_size, int) or isinstance(batch_size, bool) or \
    231             batch_size <= 0:
--> 232         raise ValueError("batch_size should be a positive integer value, "
    233                          "but got batch_size={}".format(batch_size))
    234     if not isinstance(drop_last, bool):
    235         raise ValueError("drop_last should be a boolean value, but got "
    236                          "drop_last={}".format(drop_last))

ValueError: batch_size should be a positive integer value, but got batch_size=11111111
```

I saw the warning at the beginning also in the remarks at [ValueError when pre-training BERT model using Trainer API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70263850/11154841):

> The following columns in the training set don't have a corresponding argument in BertForMaskedLM.forward and have been ignored: Text, Sentiment.

What can I do to get rid of the warning:

> The following columns in the training set don't have a corresponding argument in `DataParallel.forward` and have been ignored: attention_mask, input_ids, text. If attention_mask, input_ids, text are not expected by `DataParallel.forward`,  you can safely ignore this message.

And the error:

> ValueError: batch_size should be a positive integer value, but got batch_size=11111111"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an outdated version of transformers. I upgraded the`transformers` package from:

```py
import transformers
print(transformers.__version__)
```

Out:

```
4.19.2
```

To:

```py
pip install --upgrade transformers
```

Out:

```
4.37.1
```

Then restart the kernel in Jupyter Notebook, or you restart your IDE.